# configuration file is not getting detected

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hibernate-ogm

I am new in Hibernate and Maven. I want to use hibernateOGM. I can successfully build my code but if I run it I see these Information:

```
Aug 12, 2013 12:00:15 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Aug 12, 2013 12:00:15 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
Aug 12, 2013 12:00:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 12, 2013 12:00:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

my `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `hbm.xml` are located in **src/main/resources** .  How can I solve this problem

Comment: Are you using Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()?

Comment: The only things which I have in my main class are, these two line of code:` OgmConfiguration cfgogm=new OgmConfiguration();
            SessionFactory sessionfactory= cfgogm.buildSessionFactory();`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try placing `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF` ?

Comment: I did it, but I have the same errors and maybe more than before

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments you are using

```
OgmConfiguration cfgogm=new OgmConfiguration(); 
SessionFactory sessionfactory= cfgogm.buildSessionFactory();
```

try changing it to:

```
SessionFactory sessionfactory= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-an-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required-to-use/

Comment: thank you Juned,the Infos remains and I have no output. it looks like this: http://babakbsn.persiangig.com/annotation.png